# Buck Converter - Lack of current transfer with a higher voltage output

Tags: buck, switching-regulator

I have a custom buck controller operating on an input voltage range of about 5-30V and output of between 0-5V. The input current can only be around 500mA or the input voltage sags. The PWM is 160KHz and I selected a inductor of 68uH to try and keep it in CCM mode for the input range under reasonable current level. In DCM the controller switches the lower FET into diode emulation mode.

The load is capacitive but there is a second buck on the output of this one which limits the voltage seen. Effectively if the capacitor is less then 0.7V then the main buck will see a voltage of 3.6V on its output. The second buck maintains this 3.6V until the capacitor reaches 0.7V and then a latch causes a bypass and the capacitor is presented directly. In other words initially the main buck sees 3.6V for a while and then 0.7V+.

What I wasn't expecting is when 3.6V is presented there is almost no transfer through the inductor into the load. The capacitor is trickle charged over a minute or two and only when the latch kicks in and the 0.7V is presented does current flow as expected through the inductor.

The scope shows that under the unexpected behaviour the inductor is in DCM mode and a voltage is presented correctly, which for the capture is 13V. My questions are;

a) what is going on that prevents transfer occurring with an output of 3.6V as opposed to 0.7V and

b) how to resolve it

Thank you!

[image: scope]

Comment: Please provide a schematic for your buck converter.